# How to set ngClass based on Bootstrap's collapse?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-class

I use [collapse plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) from Bootstrap, and i also want to change class for another element accordingly (change class of fa-icon). 
I also use AngularJS and i liked the idea of using condition in ngClass like this:

```
<i ng-class="collapsableItemId.hasClass('in') ? 'fa-chevron-up' : 'fa-chevron-down'">
```

When item is not collapsed bootstrap adds `in` class to it. I want to try to change icon based on class presence in collapsable item, but did not succeed in it. In bootstrap manual there is also mentioned that collapse generates [events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events) which i could probably use, but i also do not know how.

Comment: Post the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

It should work like this. Use `ng-click` on the `collapse` toggle element to change some other scope var and then use that var in the `ng-class` of the icon..

```
  <a href="" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapse" ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen">
    <i class="fa" ng-class="(isOpen) ? 'fa-chevron-up' : 'fa-chevron-down'"></i>
  </a>  
  <div class="collapse in">
    I'm the collapsible element.
  </div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/nqLf22HCli

Comment: Press quickly several times and you will get wrong icon :) now it is implemented similar way)

Comment: This should get you started in the right direction. Make an ng-click function inside your controller instead and that issue will go away.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <i ng-class="{'fa-chevron-up': abc.isOpen ,'fa-chevron-down': !abc.isOpen  }"></i><div ng-show="abc.isOpen">Hi..This div will be show hide and  icon will be change accordingly</div>
```

Use ng-click on collapsing header and put that div which you want to collapse 
add ng-show="abc.isOpen".